# Command with multiple variables

Tags: bash, awk, variable

I am trying to make the command to return the disk usage on the folders that occupy 1+ GiBs, but somehow the second variable in the command only prints out the value of first variable. Also, the values of the totals are printed not in the column, but as a generic text, using spaces as a separator. What am I doing wrong here?

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo ls -lah -R |awk '/^total/ {print $2}' |sort -h)"; GIGS="$(echo $OUTPUT | grep G | sed 's/G//')"; echo $GIGS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newlines inside your command substitution variable OUTPUT get preserved until they are word-split when you `echo` them for the GIGS command substitution -- that's when your output turns into a single space-separated line. Quote the variable to preserve the newlines. The GIGS variable is *almost* a copy of your OUTPUT variable -- you should notice that the very first "G" in it has been deleted. You may be trying to delete all of the G's, in which case you'll want to use `sed 's/G//g'`.

End result:

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo ls -lah -R |awk '/^total/ {print $2}' |sort -h)"; GIGS="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep G | sed 's/G//g')"; echo $GIGS
```

or, broken to multiple lines:

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo ls -lah -R |awk '/^total/ {print $2}' |sort -h)";
GIGS="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep G | sed 's/G//g')"; 
echo $GIGS
```

As a possible simplification, consider doing more work in awk:

```
sudo ls -alhR | awk '/^total/ && /G$/ { print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) }' | sort -n
```

This extends your awk matching pattern to require that the line end in a 'G' (taking care of your grep), then strips the trailing (G) character from the string before printing it; then it's a simple `sort -n` at the end.